# Asynchronous functionality in "observe" function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, flowtype, mobx

Well I have the following code that *seemed* to run well:

```
observe(
    store, "user",
    async (data: {oldValue: ?UserTy, newValue: ?UserTy}) => {
        const {oldValue: previousUser, newValue: newUser} = data;

        this.entries = [];
        this.confirmed_entries = [];
        this.paid_entries = [];
        if (newUser) {
            const clear = !!previousUser;
            await this.reloadEntries(clear);
        }
        this.last_reload = new Date();
    }
);
```

Which would reload (from database) the "entries" of a the current user, upon user changing (log in/out).

Now I added flow to the mix, and suddenly I get the following error:

> Error:(47, 64) Cannot call `observe` with async function bound to `listener` because `Promise` `[1]` is incompatible with undefined `[2]` in the return value.

Looking at `mobx.js.flow` I can indeed see that it always accepts a simple function, returning `void`. the documentation is [silent](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/observe.html) on this matter. So can observer accept a promise (asynchronous) function inside it? -- Is this a "mistake" in the typing.
Or am I using observer wrong, and did I just "luck out" that the function is eventually executed?

If one cannot do this, what's the best way to rewrite this? In he end I need to call `this.reloadEntries()`, which returns a promise/makes a call to the server, upon change of user.

Answer (score 0):

So, the signature for the listener argument of this `observe` function in mobx is:

```
listener: (change: IMapChange<K, T>) => void,
```

The relevant bit is the return type, `void`, which indicates that the function should only be able to return `undefined` (or implicitly only return `undefined` by having no return statement).

Async functions *always* return a `Promise`. The mechanism of how the async/await transformation is performed and what the resultant code looks like is nicely explained in [the spec](https://tc39.github.io/ecmascript-asyncawait/#desugaring), but suffice it to say that your code is effectively replaced with code that will always return a `Promise`.

The short answer is to just not pass an async function where one is not expected. Here are some options:

1. Rework the function to just call `then` rather than rely on `await`. Probably the cleanest option in this case.
2. Turn your async function into an IIFE: `((...args) => { (async (...) {...})(...args) }`
3. Re-type your function by typing through `any`: `((myListener): any): (MyArgTypes) => void)` (don't do this)
4. Use a `$FlowFixMe` comment (don't do this either)

*So, why did it work?*

Because mobx is expecting a function that only returns `void` because it's not going to do anything with any return value. It doesn't ask for a return value because it is not going to use one. Your return value, a `Promise`, is just discarded by mobx. Therefore, it will continue to work just like it always has, despite this type error.

*Why doesn't mobx just type the return value as `any`? After all, mobx doesn't care what you return.*

Because this would be bad API design and introduce dangerous slipperiness in the typing. An API needs a reliable, sensible contract. What if a user were to pass `observe` a `listener` that returned a result because they were under the misapprehension that mobx would actually *do* something with that result? Or what if the user had, for example, passed in a higher-order function instead of the return value of that higher-order function? Both of these errors would not be caught by a less strict type in this position.

*Why does an async function always return a `Promise` even if I'm just gonna discard it anyway?*

While only returning a `Promise` based on usage *could* have been written into the spec, or maybe passing some kind of option to not return a `Promise`, it would have likely ballooned in complexity as a result with very little reward. The goal of the spec for async/await is to get the greatest possible utility without adding too much complexity. Many, but not all, async functions are being used in highly asynchronous codebases where returning a `Promise` is gonna be a better idea than not. Additionally, once a function has been declared async, there's no way to safely return a value from other than in asynchronous way (a `Promise`) without somehow digging into the body of the function and attempting to determine usage.

Comment: Thanks for the long answer, however the typing is not supported/maintained by the mobx devs, so I can't "trust" it. Reworking to use "then .. else" has the exact same actual problem: does mobx wait for the promise to finish?

Comment: Option 2 most certainly breaks everything: the async function is never awaited on and thus you're no longer certain the function executes.. ever.

Comment: Mobx doesn't wait for the promise to finish in your example. If you don't trust the flow types, how about the TypeScript source code of mobx? [Here](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/blob/master/src/api/observe.ts#L48-L53) is the corresponding type in TS, which you'll notice is basically exactly the same, and [here](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/blob/master/src/types/listen-utils.ts#L27) is where listeners get called, where you'll notice that the return value is discarded.